# ReactJS -> Router of react-router-dom not working on production build, intead is use BrowserRouter but it ignores History

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom, react-dom

Ii am trying to understand why `Router` doesn't work when I make a production build

- the bug is that every `Redirect` or going through the route path ends on a blank page it makes the push and replace respectively but its not rendering the components
- it only happens in production, on local its working fine
- I try to use `BrowserRouter as Router` but it ignores the `history.push()` and when you try to log in it doesn't redirect to the default page, but when you reload manually the page it goes without no problem, but I need to go by redirect to not make a unnecessary reload because it will consume twice all the endpoints if I make a `window.location.reload(true)`.
- `AuthService.isAuthenticated()` it's a string if it logged in it should return something like this '1234567abcdefg' if not return null
- when I log in using `BrowserRouter as Router` it's not calling the method `checkLogin` again so it's not rendering the next page but if I use `Router` instead using `BrowserRouter as Router` it works fine on localHost
- I'm using this dependencys
- ```
   "react": "16.12.0",
   node version v12.18.2
   npm version 6.14.5
   "react-dom": "16.12.0",
   "react-redux": "7.2.0",
   "react-router-dom": "5.1.2"
  ```
- my expected behavior is when it make success login it goes to '/default-page' (as it was but don't know where it's broken) right now it makes the success login but get stuck on  '/login' when it should render 'default-page'
- It has nothing to do with it .htaccess

The only warning when I use `BrowserRouter` is this `` tiny-warning.esm.js:11 Warning: <BrowserRouter> ignores the history prop. To use a custom history, use `import { Router }` instead of `import { BrowserRouter as Router }`. ``

Routing.js

```
import { Redirect, Route, Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import history from '../../history'

const checkAuthentication = (Page, props) => {
  if (!AuthService.isAuthenticated()) {
    return <Redirect to='/login' />
  }

  return Notification.permission === NotificationPermissionsType.GRANTED ? (
    <Page auth={AuthService} {...props} />
  ) : (
    <AllowNotificationsDialog />
  )
}

const checkLogin = props => {
  return AuthService.isAuthenticated() ? (
    <Redirect to='/' />
  ) : (
    <LoginPage auth={AuthService} {...props} />
  )
}

const handleExternalAuth = props => {
  return AuthService.isAuthenticated() ? (
    <Redirect to='/' />
  ) : (
    <ExternalAuthPage {...props} />
  )
}

const Routing = ({
  snackBar,
  startAppUp,
  closeSnackBar,
  intl: { formatMessage },
}) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    startAppUp() // comes from redux/root.actions
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <Router history={history}>
        <Route
          path='/'
          component={({ location }) => {
            // google analytics
            ReactGA.pageview(location.pathname)
            return null
          }}
        />
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/login' component={props => checkLogin(props)} />
          <Route path='/auth' component={props => handleExternalAuth(props)} />
          <Route
            path='/default-page'
            component={props => checkAuthentication(DefaultPage, props)}
          />
          <Route
            path='/account'
            component={props => checkAuthentication(AccountProfile, props)}
          />
          
          <Redirect to='/default-page' />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </>
  )
}

Routing.defaultProps = {}

export default Routing
```

history.js

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history
export default createBrowserHistory()
```

Comment: Are ***any*** of your `Route`s *actually* rendering a React component?

Comment: yes they are @DrewReese

`import DefaultPage from '../default-page'
import AccountProfile from '../account-profile'
import LoginPage from '../login-page'
import ExternalAuthPage from '../external-auth-page'
import AllowNotificationsDialog from '../allow-notifications-dialog'`

Comment: I meant more if you had any `Route` components rendering a React component directly. You're incorrectly using the `component` prop by passing functions the call other functions that return JSX. What is different from your production environment compared to running locally? Using the `component` prop with function will just remount components instead of rerendering them, but it would still render. Could you try making a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect and debug live?